# How to fix and commit one change in Mercurial before commiting other one?

Tags: mercurial, workflow

I have a project, which is using Mercurial, I work alone on it and often I find myself in the same situation over and over: during working on something, I realize, that other changes should be fixed and committed before I finish my current work. So, I tried to create an "Anonymous branch"

```
hg update --check PREVIOUS_REVISION
```

but unfortunately, it doesn't work with the uncommitted changes (and I really don't want to commit unfinished work). So, every time, I copy directory with sources, *revert* to the previous revision, fix, *commit*, switch back to my working copy, *pull* the change and continue my work... But it takes too much time, so maybe there are better ways to do it and just with one copy of sources? Thank you.

P.S. Probably, it's the same question as [How do I put a bunch of uncommitted changes aside while working on something else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11520047/) but my idea is "Is it possible just to leave unfinished work in the default branch in 'as is' state and then work on it later, without loading external patch?" (anyway, feel free to close it if it's a duplicate)

Comment: Why add `--check`? If you remove the `--check` flag, it will update to the previous revision while preserving (in-place merging) your local changes. Then, once you’re on the previous revision, you can commit the bits that you want to change, and it will create an anonymous branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three ways to solve task of "intermitted work"

- Using [shelve extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ShelveExtension): Save all current changes `hg shelve --all`, make needed independent changes in clean WC, commit, restore intermediate results of work, saved on step 1 `hg unshelve`
- Using anonymous branch: commit "as is" your WC, `hg up <REV>` to previous commit, make "must be before" changes, commit, return to older head, merge heads, continue work
- Using [MQ extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension): use [MQ Tutorial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqTutorial) as starting point, chapter One: "Mq for the impatient" (between qrefresh and qfinish will be pure commit in your case)

I'll prefer (and always use for different tasks) MQ

**Addition:**

For fans and admirers of "clean history" one possible change in anonymous branching workflow (avoiding merge)

- `hg commit -m "Unfinished work"` (rev M)
- `hg up -r "tip^1"`
- ...
- `hg commit -m "Base changes"` (rev N)
- `hg rebase -r M -d N` (linearize history)
- `hg up`
- ...
- `hg commit --amend -m "Full dependent change"`

**PS:** I can't see anything bad in reversed set of changeset, i.e write `a = something(data)` in CSET, and `function something (int subject) {...}` in CSET+1

Comment: So, actually my question was a duplicate... :-/ Well, thanks anyway :)

Comment: @OlegKuznetsov - while is was not marked as duplicate, it isn't duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Having commits that aren't finished isn't a bad thing. It helps you survive things like your hard drive crashing. Why not commit your in-progress code with a commit message like "this is in progress", do whatever else you need to, then continue working on it?

Old commits are, by definition, unfinished. That's why you committed more things after them. Don't worry about the state of your old repository.

Of course, you should make cure you're working in feature branches, so you can push your code to a branch that isn't `default`.

Answer (score 0):

If the 'must' changes are different hunks of codes, why not `hg record`, and select the 'must' hunks and commit before the others.